# How to make a rsa encryption C++ and decryption C#

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, cryptography

I have a problem - encryption communication with the client, server written in C# and the client on the C++ (Windows MacOs Linux).

I generates a key for Rijndael and RSA encrypt it and send the server, the server Use Rijndael to encrypt messages.

My problem is that I can`t encrypt RSA, I have a xml file with the public key

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>pmmv...</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

how can I use C++? 
may have a library for all platforms or better algorithm that would include it in the draft

I found in google one algorithm but it requires public key format for BigInt.
How to get out of XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presentation format is RFC 3275, [XML-Signature Syntax and Processing](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3275.txt).

You will need to parse the RFC 3275 RSAKeyValue, then put it in an OpenSSL RSA structure.

Its somewhat painful.... are you sure you want to see it? (The XML parsing is left as an exercise to the reader, but it uses the values you provided above).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int ret = -1;

    char nz[] = "sqprMX0n4y1gmmgpTt6pHb870k5U0MIuXixidD+S8foQf5Bb"
             "FS44kth2uWDKzXOXqiONxIPHPb+84XdxrRi2O7bvLysztgrF"
             "eU8oNDMeuIwJOKVQzKoJ1vGqjBKiA9w48oQKxvO+Ck3GmObW"
             "67LFNcrt50sEco2/OMmrpiH3W8hRx55TcR1flCJduU0/6jA7"
             "Yct9ZfhOw5wBq6o5IwiT8Mi1R6LVq9sTzSNAWHC/bFcEONkt"
             "z6NgUKbFKtt+mTfFGToiwPB1L4TecGyTIweH84nl8jVAngcM"
             "vvFP415Eg1kd9PJbRqrIESM5AU1YcsapWV3bsqEGVS2y+r5N"
             "4yzXPCYRCRyFWJSnNVlax+gtDFTNz3m9UT8m2E7elGe5hPhR"
             "6nN3votzBNvTeQ4Lwc5JDIvnWUg7aOdVIXnHQbBqEQke79BX"
             "xIv8tzVPczGkFqFExkmPPQQv8zJvBKkIYc+BFJtkylBiZfQX"
             "0590NS3L1y31VSeXn8Ncx2/ceJfUXsMWJ3sQ+dk51MKBJ2LL"
             "oyJq8IgloBLnXWvlYZ+tkzRVTExFR277V3Jr17DeTOMQGEg5"
             "HqRkbDDVGPTl2RvC2S2BTe7+r9xNzyAZMieVjZLZgb6icE6u"
             "SJFcu4qqJ1khQUjW7taymqW8Ao3oEiCUJKvRpZcJPMN+JtMn"
             "ji+2we17ytk=";

    char ez[] = "AQAB";

    BIO* nn = NULL, *ee = NULL;
    BIO* b1 = NULL, *b2 = NULL;
    RSA* rsa = NULL;

    nn = BIO_new_mem_buf(nz, strlen(nz));
    if(!nn) { ret = 1; goto done; }

    ee = BIO_new_mem_buf(ez, strlen(ez));
    if(!ee) { ret = 2; goto done; }

    b1 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    if(!b1) { ret = 3; goto done; }

    b2 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    if(!b2) { ret = 4; goto done; }

    /* If you leave these out even though you   */
    /* are reading, then BIO_read will return 0 */
    /* and BIO_should_retry will return false   */
    BIO_set_flags(b1, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    BIO_set_flags(b2, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);

    nn = BIO_push(b1, nn);
    if(!nn) { ret = 5; goto done; }

    ee = BIO_push(b2, ee);
    if(!ee) { ret = 6; goto done; }

    rsa = RSA_new();
    if(rsa == NULL) { ret = 7; goto done; }

    unsigned char buff[4096];
    const int bsize = sizeof(buff);
    int rr = 0, rd = 0;

    /* See http://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=123171064303018&w=2 */
    /* for this contorted goodness */
    rd = 0;
    do {
        rr = BIO_read(nn, buff + rd, bsize - rd);
        if(rr < 0) { ret = 8; goto done; } /* failed */

        rd += rr;
    } while (rr > 0 || BIO_should_retry(nn));

    if(rd == 0) { ret = 9; goto done; }

    rsa->n = BN_bin2bn(buff, rd, NULL);
    if(rsa->n == NULL) { ret = 10; goto done; }

    rd = 0;
    do {
        rr = BIO_read(ee, buff + rd, bsize - rd);
        if(rr < 0) { ret = 11; goto done; } /* failed */

        rd += rr;
    } while (rr > 0 || BIO_should_retry(ee));

    if(rd == 0) { ret = 12; goto done; }

    rsa->e = BN_bin2bn(buff, rd, NULL);
    if(rsa->e == NULL) { ret = 13; goto done; }

    /***** Paydirt *****/

    RSA_print_fp(stdout, rsa, 0);

    ret = 0;

done:

    if(ret != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse and validate RSA key\n");

    if(rsa)
       RSA_free(rsa), rsa = NULL;

    if(nn)
        BIO_free_all(nn), nn = NULL;

    if(ee)
        BIO_free_all(ee), ee = NULL;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: very well this works, but the server does not understand me, says can not decrypt the message

Comment: Check if client can decrypt encrypted data without server. 
Also check if you have the same XML data on a client side and on a server side. 
Save data to a files on a server and on a client and compare these files using fc.

Comment: can decrypt 
and the server displays the error "bad data"

Comment: works 
set RSA_PKCS1_PADDING 

a great big thank you

Answer (score 0):

By parsing the XML, base 64 decode the text within the text and create an unsigned big integer with the resulting byte array, one for the modulus and one for the public exponent (although the latter may always be 0x10001 or 65537 - the fourth number of Fermat F4 - as it is now for the current key pair generator).

If you only need to do this once you can also base 64 decode the string and copy the result in the C++ code manually.